# Replace " ’ " with " ' " in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, apostrophe

I'm grabbing a string from the database that could be something like `String’s Title` however I need to replace the `’` with a `'` so that I can pass the string to an external API. I've used just about every variation of escaped strings in `str_replace()` that I can think of to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `str_replace(utf8_encode('’'), "'", $str)`? What are the respective encodings of the strings?

Comment: `preg_replace("’","'",$string);`

Comment: Can you show what variations you have tried? THis may be a character set issue.

Comment: Try this `$h = str_replace('"','\'',$string);`

Comment: What are the encodings of each string?

Comment: You can see the page here: http://www.spoilerseason.com/card/akromas-memorial/

I'm trying to do the replacement in $cardnametitle

Comment: @mike-r according to the rendered web page it seems to be an encoding problem. Please, could you specify the exact encoding used in the database?

Comment: Database encoding is UTF-8 and collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this:

```
echo str_replace('&#8217;', "'", $cardnametitle);
//Outputs: String's Title
```

Edit: I believe that entries in your database have been `htmlentities`ed.

Note: I'm pretty sure this is not a good solution, even though it did solve your problem I think there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: In the question it is already specified that the use of str_replace has been tried! Why nobody read the full question? It's certainly more complicated (maybe encoding related) than a simple `str_replace`!

Comment: @fsehat, I believe YOU haven't read the full question. OP hasn't provided any code, for all we know he might've written `str_replace('’', ''', "String’s Title");`
So, with the provided information, that's about the best thing can be provided

Comment: In the question comments everyone is asking him to provide more details about the implementation. So please wait a few minutes before posting the same answer than @Basic Bridge and another one who even deleted his answer.

Comment: Hi Adnan, thanks for the response. You can see the page here: http://www.spoilerseason.com/card/akromas-memorial/

Comment: @fsehat. Alright, here's how this site work. You read the question, and you try your best to answer using the provided information. When new information arise we edit the answer to give a better code/explanation.

Comment: @mike-r could you please specify your database encoding?

Comment: @MikeR, now that you posted the link, we see it's an encoding problem. Now we edit our answers to provide you with the best solution possible. If you add more info, further editing will be done.

Comment: Database encoding is UTF-8 and collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @MikeR, I have edited my answer, can you try it now please. (it's just to test something)

Comment: I've tried it. Your edited method is the first one: http://www.spoilerseason.com/card/akromas-memorial/

Comment: Also, if you don't mind taking the time to explain what exactly was going wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @MikeR, I honestly don't know for sure. But I believe you're using some input encoding which making characters like `’` be stored in the DB like `&#8217;`, it might also be encoding problem, but I don't have enough experience to say for sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stdin = mb_str_replace('’', '\'', $stdin);
```

Implementation of `mb_str_replace()` here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#107631

I mean this:

```
<?php
function mb_str_replace($needle, $replacement, $haystack) {
   return implode($replacement, mb_split($needle, $haystack));
}
echo mb_str_replace('’', "'", "String’s Title");
```

It may solve encoding problems.

Comment: Thanks but that method did not work: http://www.spoilerseason.com/card/akromas-memorial/

For what it's worth, database encoding is UTF-8 and collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$s = "String’s Title";
$h = str_replace("’","'",$s);
echo $h;
```

Also can Try with preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace('/\’/',"'","String’s Title");
```

Comment: In the question it is already specified that the use of str_replace has been tried!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `str_replace()` is not working for you.

I feel you haven't tried it in correct way.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/hWneoESh)**

```
<?php
    $str = "String’s Title";
    echo str_replace('’', '\'', $str) . "\n";
    echo str_replace("’", "'", $str);
?>
```

### OUTPUT:

```
String's Title
String's Title
```

### UPDATE 1:

You may need to try setting the header as

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue trying to replace apostrophes with underscores... I ended up having to write this (and this was for a WordPress site):

```
$replace = array(",","'","’"," ","&#8217;","&#8211;");
$downloadTitle = str_replace( $replace,"_",get_the_title($gallery_id));
```

I'm new to PHP myself, and realize this is pretty hideous code, but it worked for me.  I realized it was the "’" that REALLY needed to be factored in for some reason.