# Find Every Occurence of [B] and Replace with Proper <b> Tag in PHP

Tags: php

This code prints out the text in a column:

```
echo "<td colspan='5'>" . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
```

When it provides the paragraph of text it includes incorrectly formatted bold tags which look like [B].  What I want to do is replace these with either a `<b>` tag or a blank space.

Not sure how to do this with PHP.

Comment: Did you try googling "replace text in php"?

Comment: You could look for BBcode parsers

Comment: Take a look at [PHP - String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: [B] for <b> but what is for </b>

Comment: <strong> is more semanticly correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace " ’ " with " ' " in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350466/replace-with-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`$row['DESCRIPTION'] = str_replace(array('[B]','[!B]'), array('<b>', '</b>'), $row['DESCRIPTION']);`
```

Comment: Yep, although `array` should be written in lower-case (fix and I'll upvote).

Comment: I prefer it that way ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I did research this topic but nothing was coming up as simplified as this.  The only thing with your answer is that you missed the ' off the end of the first '[B]'

Answer (score 2):

```
If [B] for <b> and [!B] for </b>
```

Use:

```
<?php

$row['DESCRIPTION'] = "In this string the [B]word[!B] is bolded";

$text = str_replace("[B]","<b>",$row['DESCRIPTION']);

$text = str_replace("[!B]","</b>",$text);

echo $text;

?>
```

Output:

In this string the **word** is bolded

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` function may help in your case.